# Retrieve values from excel using poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to get the column values for a specific row in a excel using poi methods.

I am able to get the values but the problem is I want the values only from second column.

```
public static ArrayList<String> GetBusinessComponentList() throws IOException{


        String Tcname = "TC02_AggregateAutoByPassRO_CT";
        ArrayList<String> arrayListBusinessFlow ;   
        arrayListBusinessFlow = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(oFile);
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInput);
        sheet = wb.getSheet("Business Flow");

        int rownr = findRow(sheet, Tcname);
            row = sheet.getRow(rownr);  
                                          for (Cell cell : row) {
                                        String arr = cell.getStringCellValue();                  
                      arrayListBusinessFlow.add(arr);         
                    }                               
                  return arrayListBusinessFlow;
        }
    private static int findRow(HSSFSheet sheet, String cellContent){              

        for (Row row : sheet) {
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals(cellContent)) {
                        return row.getRowNum();  
                    }
                }
            }
        }               
        return 0;
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[TC02_AggregateAutoByPassRO_CT, 
StrategicUINewBusiness.Login, 
StrategicUINewBusiness.CustomerSearch, 
StrategicUINewBusiness.NamedInsured, 
StrategicUINewBusiness.InsuranceScoreByPass, 
StrategicUINewBusiness.VehiclePage, 
StrategicUINewBusiness.DriverPage, 
StrategicUINewBusiness.ViolationPage, 
StrategicUINewBusiness.UnderwritingPage, 
StrategicUINewBusiness.CoveragePage, 
StrategicUINewBusiness.Portfolio, 
StrategicUINewBusiness.BillingPage, 
StrategicUINewBusiness.FinalSalePage, 
StrategicUINewBusiness.PolicyConfirmation, , , ]
```

But I do not want my test case name when I am getting.

Please help me what changes i needed to do. thanks!

Comment: your code searches on all cells for the returned row numbers. if you need only second column on rows, you can specify the column index.

Comment: No i do need all the column values for a specifc row. It just that im finding the row based on the testcase name. So when i retrieve i dont want my test case name.

Comment: how do i set the column index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the code you're using to iterate over cells only returns cells with content or styling, and skips totally empty ones. You need to change to one of the other ways of iterating over cells, so you can control it to read from the second column onwards.

If you look at the [Apache POI Documentation on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator), you'll see a lot more details on the two main ways to iterate.

For your case, you'll want something like:

```
// We want to read from the 2nd column onwards, zero based
int firstColumn = 1;

// Always fetch at least 4 columns
int MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT = 5;
// Work out the last column to go to
int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT);

// To format cells into strings
DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();

// Iterate over the cells
for (int cn = firstColumn; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
    Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
    if (c == null) {
        // The spreadsheet is empty in this cell
    } else {
        // Do something useful with the cell's contents

        // eg get the cells value as a string
        String cellAsString = df.formatCellValue(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Cell cell=row.getCell(1);` and also you can use `sheet.getLastRowNum()` to get the number last row on the sheet.

```
for (int i=0;i<=row.getLastCellNum();i++) {
      if (i!=1){
        //your stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. all i wanted is to ignore the value from column 1(i.e. Test case name or cellcontent which im comparing). So please let me know what should i be doing. Also "for (Cell cell : row)" im getting error if i use row.getcell(1).

Comment: pardon me, im new to java

Comment: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

Comment: int rownr = findRow(sheet, Tcname);
   row = sheet.getRow(rownr); 
                   for (Cell cell : row.getCell(1)) { /// on this line
               String arr = cell.getStringCellValue();         
          arrayListBusinessFlow.add(arr);       
        }           
         return arrayListBusinessFlow;

Comment: In that case im only printing second column, im not printing the contents of other column of the row. I just wanted to ignore the content from first column.

Comment: Why? if you une for (int i=0;i<=row.getLastCellNum();i++) {
      if (i!=1){
        //your stuff
     }
} you process all cell exclude 2

Comment: im getting Null pointer exception in " String  arr = cell.getStringCellValue(); " but im able to get the contents from second column.